# Finger Code in perl - Not able to execute

Tags: perl

**Error:**

Syntax error: end of file unexpected

**Below is the Code**

I changed.

```
"#!/usr/local/bin/perl"
```

The actual program is

```
#!/local/perl5/bin/perl5.003

use Socket;

$sockaddr = 'S n a4 x8';

$host = $ARGV[0];
$them = $host;
$port = 79;
print "Finger $host: \n";
$hostname = ``;
`nslookup $host |grep Name:  >> $test`;
print $test;
#($name, $aliases, $proto) = getprotobyname('tcp');

($name, $aliases, $port) = getservbyname($port, 'tcp') unless $port =~ /^\d+$/;
($name, $aliases, $type, $len, $thisaddr) = gethostbyname($hostname);
$n1 = $name;
($name, $aliases, $type, $len, $thataddr) = gethostbyname($them);

$this = pack($sockaddr, &AF_INET, 0, $thisaddr);
$that = pack($sockaddr, &AF_INET, $port, $thataddr);

socket(S, &PF_INET, &SOCK_STREAM, $proto) || die "socket: $!";

bind(S, $this) || die "bind: $!";
connect(S, $that);

select(S); $| = 1; select(stdout);

print S "\n\n";

while (<S>) {print $_;};
```

Comment: In order to format your code, select it and hit CTRL·K in edition box. for future questions.

Comment: thank u...will make sure that next time

Comment: Can't you use something better than perl 5.003 ? It was released in 1996. As for the issues in the code, $test and $proto are never initialized (proto is commented) and the overall thing seems unstable. Did you try "perl -w foo.pl hostname" and "perl -d foo.pl hostname" ? in debug, use "n" to execute the next line and "print $this" or "x @that" to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
`nslookup $host |grep Name:  >> $test`;
```

`$test` is undefined at that point, so you're asking the shell to execute `nslookup whatever.com |grep Name:  >>`. Where is the shell supposed to redirect the output to?

If you set `$test` to be something, like a filename.. or even `$test = "$host.txt";` it will get you further.

Nothing to do with your Perl version, although being able to `use strict;use warnings` does help, as it would've caught the above error.